# Normalize the data in a dataframe in the range [0,1]

Tags: python, dataframe, normalization, data-processing

I'm trying to implement a paper where PIMA Indians Diabetes dataset is used. This is the dataset after imputing missing values:

```
Preg    Glucose     BP     SkinThickness    Insulin     BMI    Pedigree Age Outcome
0   1   148.0   72.000000   35.00000    155.548223  33.600000   0.627   50  1
1   1   85.0    66.000000   29.00000    155.548223  26.600000   0.351   31  0
2   1   183.0   64.000000   29.15342    155.548223  23.300000   0.672   32  1
3   1   89.0    66.000000   23.00000    94.000000   28.100000   0.167   21  0
4   0   137.0   40.000000   35.00000    168.000000  43.100000   2.288   33  1
5   1   116.0   74.000000   29.15342    155.548223  25.600000   0.201   30  0
```

The description:

```
df.describe()
      Preg       Glucose        BP        SkinThickness  Insulin     BMI    Pedigree    Age
count768.000000 768.000000  768.000000  768.000000  768.000000  768.000000  768.000000  768.000000
mean0.855469    121.686763  72.405184   29.153420   155.548223  32.457464   0.471876    33.240885
std 0.351857    30.435949   12.096346   8.790942    85.021108   6.875151    0.331329    11.760232
min 0.000000    44.000000   24.000000   7.000000    14.000000   18.200000   0.078000    21.000000
25% 1.000000    99.750000   64.000000   25.000000   121.500000  27.500000   0.243750    24.000000
50% 1.000000    117.000000  72.202592   29.153420   155.548223  32.400000   0.372500    29.000000
75% 1.000000    140.250000  80.000000   32.000000   155.548223  36.600000   0.626250    41.000000
max 1.000000    199.000000  122.000000  99.000000   846.000000  67.100000   2.420000    81.000000
```

The description of normalization from the paper is as follows:

*As part of our data preprocessing, the original data values are scaled so as to fall within a small speciﬁed range of [0,1] values by performing normalization of the dataset. This will improve speed and reduce runtime complexity. Using the Z-Score we normalize our value set V to obtain a new set of normalized values V’ with the equation below:
V'=V-Y/Z
where  V’= New normalized value, V=previous value, Y=mean and Z=standard deviation*

```
 z=scipy.stats.zscore(df)
```

But when I try to run the code above, I'm getting negative values and values greater than one i.e., not in the range [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't finish the process: all you've done is to get the vector of Z-scores.  You have to apply the rest of the specified calculations.

The Z-score indicates how many sdevs (standard deviations) that element is above/below the mean.  You still have to subtract the mean and divide by the sdev to get the canonical [-1, 1] normalization.  I expect you can now alter the needed algebra to get your desired [0, 1] interval.